# Athena Presto parse_duration not registered

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena, presto

I have an Athena DB, and I'm trying to use `parse_duration` Presto function. For some reason it doesn't work (says the function is not registered).

Did someone had the same problem and manage to solve it? Or have an idea for other function that I can use?

`parse_duration` function exists in Presto since May 2017, so I assume it should be supported in Athena already, isn't it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [SQL Queries, Functions, and Operators - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/functions-operators-reference-section.html):

> Amazon Athena query engine is based on Presto 0.172.

The `parse_duration` function appears to have been added in [Presto 0.176](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/release/release-0.176.html).

Thus, it is not available in Amazon Athena. (As of the time of writing this answer.)

Comment: `parse_duration` was added in 0.176 (https://prestodb.io/docs/current/release/release-0.176.html), not 0.204

Answer (score 0):

I needed `parse_duration` for my query in Athena, but my particular use case was to parse a number of seconds to an interval, for which I did:

```
SELECT (interval '1' second) * number_of_seconds AS duration_in_seconds
```

While this does not directly exactly answer the question, it may be useful to people that arrive to this question with my same issue.